# What is this tiny plant with yellow orchid-like flowers?

Tags: identification

[image]

This stem holds 9 tiny orchid-like flowers, some still yet to open. The leaves only measure approx 2cm long, and it looks like little tendrils coming at leaf/stem joint.

It is in my garden in Oxfordshire England. I saw the flowers while pulling up unwanted stuff. It's very tiny, thought I'd got a little orchid at first, it does look as though it could be from the pea family,

Answer (score 2):

I would place this in the pea family - the flower shape, the tendrils and the squareish stem are a hint. [This website](http://www.wildflowers-and-weeds.com/Plant_Families/Fabaceae.htm) illustrates the characteristics quite nicely.

This appears to be a member of the Lathyrus genus, commonly known as sweet peas. In gardens, one would probably first think of [l. odoratus](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sweet_pea), the classic sweet pea, but there are a few "cousins" with narrower leaves like [l. sylvestris](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lathyrus_sylvestris). While typical flower colors are in the pink-to-lavender range, sweet peas have been breed in yellow-orange tones as well.

Taking the origin and further description into account, I'd suggest [l. pratensi (Meadow Vetchling)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lathyrus_pratensis) as best match, various sources show more or less distinct stripes on the "banner", yours being of the more distinct type.

Comment: It is in my garden, I saw the flowers while pulling up unwanted stuff. It's very tiny, thought I'd got a little orchid at first, I agree it does look as though it could be from pea family. –  Yvonne Pickwick 34 secs ago   edit

Answer (score 0):

Most likely Birdfoot Trefoil, the bees love it!